# c++ UTF-8 string erro starting at 10xxxxxx with cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, rest, utf-8, cpprest-sdk

I have been working with the cpprestsdk for quite a bit, and have not been having this issue at all until today. I am not sure what changed, but after debugging it for awhile, I am confused as to why this is happening.
When converting a utf-8 string to a wchar_t, to be used with the rest calls, I am getting the error "UTF-8 string character can never start with 10xxxxxx" 
The cpp file that throws this error is shown here at line 280: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/src/utilities/asyncrt_utils.cpp

I copied the code into my program to try and figure out why this is happening, and here is what I have: Note: *tmp is an iterator for a string vector

```
`std::string str = *tmp->safe; //*tmp->safe == "WW-Department-Zone-OS" 
const size_t sSize = str.size();
const char* const sData = str.data();
size_t result{ sSize };
for (size_t index = 0; index < sSize;) {
    const char c{ sData[index++] };
    if ((c & 0x40) == 0)
        std::cout << "String starts with 10xxxxxx\n";
}`
```

When using breakpoints, I noticed that the error is thrown when 'c' == '-' character and the character after it is -40 'Ø'.  If anyone has any input on why this is happening, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (namely, enough for a call that gives this error when you expect it to succeed). Also, `c & 0x40` checks for the second-highest bit, not the highest.

Comment: Before I make a call, I need to convert all data to string_t/wchar_t, so it errors out well before it even makes the call. It gets thrown when it makes the conversion to wchar_t. For example

 'PasswordName = utility::conversions::to_string_t(pwN);' 
pwN == "root-unknown-several appliance local logins-vROps  Appliance Root"

Since the function is very large, I will post a small one for an example.

Comment: As long as the example follows the link I gave. Something complete that we can run as is, but minimal, with all unnecessary code removed, while still being verifiable so that we can get the same error. You'll find that an alarmingly high percentage of the time, creating a proper MCVE will lead to you discovering the answer before even asking the question.

Comment: `pplx::task<void>Call(){ 
utility::string_t uri = L"rest.svc/Account", wPasswordName = L"", Safe=L""; 
string str="root-unknown-several appliance local logins-vROps Appliance Root";
string safe="WW-IES-GESM-NIX"; 
wPasswordName = utility::conversions::to_string_t(str);
wSafe = utility::conversions::to_string_t(safe);
json::value jAccount, jSafe; 
jSafe[L"Safe"]=json::value::string(wSafe); jSafe[L"accountName"]=json::value::string(wPasswordName); jAccount[L"account"]=jSafe;`

Comment: Here is the call
    `http_client client(L"myserver.com");
    http_request reqeust(methods::Post);
    request.set_request_uri(uri);
    request.set_body(jAccount.serialize().c_sr());
    request.headers().add(L"Authorization", token);
    request.headers().set_content(L"application/json");
    return client.request(request).then([&](http_response response){
    std::cout << response.status_code();
    if(response.status_code() == status_codes::Created){
    std::cout << "Success";
    }
    });`

Comment: Sorry for crappy formatting of code. I don't seem to have the adding of code in comments down quite right yet.

Comment: I did notice this was happening in my code which looks like corrupted data to me.
If I dig down in the locals view while debugging, I see this as my variable under the _Buf
Buf 0x0319a910 "ˆï\x15\x3" char[16]
[0] -120 'ˆ' char
[1] -17 'ï' char
[2] 21 '\x15' char
[3] 3 '\x3' char
[4] 0 '\0' char
[5] 11 '\v' char
[6] 117 'u' char
[7] 112 'p' char
[8] 0 '\0' char
[9] 0 '\0' char
[10] 0 '\0' char
[11] 0 '\0' char
[12] 15 '\xf' char
[13] 0 '\0' char
[14] 0 '\0' char
[15] 0 '\0' char
Under the _ptr for the same variable it shows the correct data.

Comment: @chris
I think the origin of the problem is when it is reading the data from the csv file into a string vector.The first entry it gets which is suppose to be "Password_name" ends up getting read and stored as "ï»¿Password_name" which ends up breaking the whole program when I need to access the data.

Here is my code for parsing the csv file
`bool ReadCSVFile(){
 std::string file = "csvFile.csv";
std::vector<std::vector <std::string>> buffer;
std::ifstream configFile;
configFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
try{std::string line;
configFile.open(file.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);`

Comment: @chris
`while(configFile.is_open())
  {
   if (!std::getline(configFile, line))
    break;
   std::istringstream ss(line);
   std::vector<std::string> record;
   int counter = 0;
   while (ss)
   {
    std::string s;
    if (!std::getline(ss, s, ','))
    {
     if (ss.eof())
      record.push_back("");
    }
     record.push_back(s);
   }
   buffer.push_back(record);
  }
 }
 catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
 {
  throw e;
  return false;
 }
return true;
}`

Comment: When I open the csv file in a text editor, It all looks right.  First row Shown below: 
Password_name,Safe,SafeDescription,Password,PolicyID,Address,UserName,Type,LogonDomain,ADGroup,Comment,Description,Group,GroupPlatformID,CPMDisabled,DisabledReason,ResetImmediately,DSN,ClientDN,ServerDN,ExtraPass1Name,ExtraPass1Safe,ExtraPass1Folder,ExtraPass2Name,ExtraPass2Safe,ExtraPass2Folder,ExtraPass3Name,ExtraPass3Safe,ExtraPass3Folder

Comment: It's rather hard to go from the comments and fragments of code. The question should be edited and you should take out as much code as possible, aiming for as little as you can while still reproducing the error while still being complete enough to copy, paste, and compile as is.

Comment: @chris
I have removed as much of it as I could already for it to still be as close to my original as I can get it. Not sure what else I can remove.

Comment: Trying to be close to the original code is misguided. As far as things go for someone trying to find the problem, it's enough to have some written context rather than bloating the code with context. For example, you might be making a string class and have the arguments to `strcpy` switched deep in the `const char*` constructor. The MCVE after removing as much cruft as possible would be `#include <cstring> #include <iostream> int main() { char src[] = "abc"; char dst[] = "def"; std::strcpy(src, dst); std::cout << dst; }`, with an explanation that this prints "def" instead of the expected "abc".

Comment: It's easy for someone to run that, see the problem in action, and play around with it to fix it. As far as the question goes, the only context necessary is "I'm trying to make a string class to learn about C strings". The problem here isn't that the string class isn't working, it's that `strcpy` isn't giving expected behaviour. The code doesn't have the class because it isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. Of course at this point, it's easy to look up `strcpy` and see that the destination comes first. This is why simply creating an MCVE leads you to solution so often.

Comment: If it's still non-obvious by that point, then at least it's far easier than before for the people who have enough experience to figure it out.

Comment: @chris
After further digging around, the reason my code started behaving differently was because the csv file got saved as a CSV UTF-8 format instead of just csv.  Once I saved it back to the non utf-8 format it read the file as expected.  

Thanks for the help Chris!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit too late but the solution for this problem is quite strange but I will post the anser as it's much simply to find it on this forum than in other forums.
I had the same problem vith VS 2019 and the same in Qt creator but I finally found the answer.

As mentioned here: https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/1142
in the last message, you should use cpprest_2_10d.lib for the debug mode and cpprest_2_10.lib for release.
If you used vcpkg to install cpprestsdk then the debug version of the library is in the "debug/lib" directory and the library for realease is just in "lib" directory.

Thanks to the github.com members for posting the answer, it really saved my time.